# Faster way to target same selector in a jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an output page (that I can't control) that has a really bad format. I'm using jQuery to loop through the elements and reorganize them to meet design specs.

I'm compiling strings using code similar to that below, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it run faster? As you can see, the .html() I'm sniffing out is in children of the same parent element.

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    var address = $('.cellInnerWrapper .row-content .address a .addressNumber', this).html() + 
                  $('.cellInnerWrapper .row-content .address a .addressDirection', this).html() + 
                  $('.cellInnerWrapper .row-content .address a .addressName', this).html();
});
```

This just seems incredibly slow and repetitive to me, but I'm not the best at JavaScript and jQuery and don't know how to simplify it / speed it up.

Here's the original HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="cellInnerWrapper">
        <div class="rowContent">
            <div class="address">
                <a href="URL">
                    <span class="addressNumber">17080 </span>
                    <span class="addressDirection"></span>
                    <span class="addressName">Iron Springs Road</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML strcture?

Comment: I would use `$('.parent .cellInnerWrapper .row-content .address a').each(...)`

Comment: I can't use .each on the <a> because there are individual elements that just contain commas and spaces and junk data that aren't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').each(function(){
        var address;
        var a = $('.cellInnerWrapper .rowContent .address a');
        address = a.find('.addressNumber').html()+a.find('.addressDirection')+a.find('.addressName').html();
    });
});
```

I adjusted to your html structure. Don't forget to use `document.ready` event to make sure the html structure was loaded before the script is executed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is definitely cleaner! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo. You can store your common element in a new object and then access all the required elements that way you won't have to navigate the DOM every time.

```js
$('.parent').each(function(){
        var anchor = $('.cellInnerWrapper .rowContent .address a');
        var address = anchor.find('.addressNumber').html() +
        anchor.find('.addressDirection').html() + 
        anchor.find('.addressName').html();
        console.log(address);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="cellInnerWrapper">
        <div class="rowContent">
            <div class="address">
                <a href="URL">
                    <span class="addressNumber">17080 </span>
                    <span class="addressDirection"></span>
                    <span class="addressName">Iron Springs Road</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Giving this a +1 even though it's the same solution @Keloo gave.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $('.parent').each(function(){
            var a=$('.cellInnerWrapper').find('div.address').children('a').html();
$('div.newaddress').html(a);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="cellInnerWrapper">
            <div class="rowContent">
                <div class="address">
                    <a href="URL">
                        <span class="addressNumber">17080 </span>
                        <span class="addressDirection"></span>
                        <span class="addressName">Iron Springs Road</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="newaddress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

try this one.

Comment: This would be ideal, if I was using every element nested under the <a>, but as I commented on my OP, I'm not.